# continue an interrupted stream python pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl, data-stream

I am implementing a pycurl connection to a live datastream, sometimes the connection to the data stream disconnects and I am unsure as to how to continue the interrupted stream right away. I am not worried about the lose of data if the stream is interrupted. Below is the code I am using which works but doesn't have the logic of reconnecting immediately if the stream is disconnected.

```
import pycurl
import urllib
import json
STREAM_URL = "https://website"
class Client:
  def __init__(self):
    self.buffer = ""
    self.conn = pycurl.Curl()
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, STREAM_URL)
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: token','Accept: application/json'])
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, self.on_receive)
    self.conn.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 2500)
    self.conn.perform()
  def on_receive(self, data):
    print(data)
client = Client()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to rescue `pycurl.error` exception and repeat the connection in this case.